# Do I need to change the schema of my mongoDB due to this issue?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, mongodb-query

I'm working with a MongoDB database where each data row is like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c1bbcfbfe78c90007af2676"),
"_class" : "dasdas.dsadas.eewrewrdsfsa.dsad",
"deviceid" : 943955,
"checkid" : "23303140",
"dsc247" : 1,
"description" : "Windows-Dienst-Überprüfung - SQL Server VSS Writer",
"checkstatus" : "testerror",
"extra" : "96 fortlaufende Fehler, Öffnen des Dienstes nicht möglich",
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T15:55:00.000Z"),
"consecutiveFails" : 96,
"emailalerts" : 1,
"smsalerts" : 0,
"emailrecoveryalerts" : 1,
"smsrecoveryalerts" : 0,
"servertime" : ISODate("2018-12-20T16:02:02.000Z")
}
```

The database has the following indexes:

```
_id
datetime
deviceid_description
deviceid_description_checkstatus_datetime
```

The rows are ordered by *datetime*, but I want to access the data based on *servertime* field. The problem is that even a simple query like this:

```
db.check.find(
    {
           servertime: new ISODate("2018-12-21 23:17:30.000Z")
    }        
).limit(1)
```

takes **30 seconds** to give back the result, and if I try to execute any query beyond that it takes forever!!

However, if I do the above query based on datatime it finishes in **0.016 seconds**!!

Is there any way around this problem?!

Do I have to change the DB schema? how difficult and time-consuming it would be?!

I use Robo mongo framework. Is there any faster platform to access the data?

The database has SQL charactristics, what about converting that to SQL format?

Comment: Do you have an index on `servertime`…?

Comment: @deceze I have index on datetime, _id, and deviceid_description_checkstatus_datetime

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#view-existing-indexes

Comment: @deceze No, It does not!

Comment: So… create one?

Comment: @deceze how difficult is that? Do I need write access?

Comment: Please start here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: @deceze How long would it take to create a new index for a collection of 700 million entries with 15 fields? I need to decide on when to do it to make it less disruptive regarding other users.